# Hashmap method to sum

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, sum

so i have the following task:

Given is the following class:

```
    public class Konto {
    private final String inhaber;
    private double guthaben;

    public Konto(String inhaber) {
        this.inhaber = inhaber;
    }
    public String getInhaber() {
        return inhaber;
    }
    public double getGuthaben() {
        return guthaben;
    }
    public void einzahlen(double betrag) {
        guthaben += betrag;
    }
    public void auszahlen(double betrag) {
        guthaben -= betrag;
    }

}
```

Using these classes, implement another class named Bank with the following properties:

- The attribute named accounts is a directory of all
  Account numbers and related accounts
  (java.util.HashMap) and should be initialized in a default constructor of the class.
- Write the addKonto method to add a new account of type Account, a getKonto method to query an account by its number, and a method called removeKonto that deletes an account with a specific number.
- Implement a getGesamtguthaben method that returns the sum of the Balance(guthaben) of all bank accounts.
- Write a containsKonto method that checks if an account with the given number exists in the bank and returns a corresponding Boolean value.

this is my code:

```
package Bank;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Bank {
    private Map<String, Konto> konten;

    public Bank() {
        konten = new HashMap<String, Konto>();
    }

    public Konto addKonto(Konto konto) {

        return konten.put(konto.getInhaber(), konto);

    }

    public String getKonto(String kontonr) {
        if(konten.containsKey(kontonr)) {
            return kontonr;
    }
        return null;
    }



    public Konto removeKonto(String kontonr) {
        return konten.remove(kontonr);
        }


    public double getGesamtguthaben() {
        for(double guthaben : konten) {

        }

    }
    public boolean containsKonto(String kontonr) {
        if(konten.containsKey(kontonr)) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

SO my question is how do i sum the balance of all Bank Accounts with a own method? And are the other methods correct? all help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, this community is not a review service for code. Determining "code is correct" is an essential skill of a programming, it is part of your **learning** efforts. How? By thinking up how you could **test** your code. Meaning: what kind of tests would you need, how to write them down, how to effectively run them. Asking for help with the sum method is somewhat OK (close to being to broad, unless you have written your first approach yourself) ... but "review everything" isn't in the scope of this community.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Map.entrySet` to iterate over the entries.

```
double sum = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Konto> entrySet : konten.entrySet()) {
     sum += entrySet.getValue().getGuthaben();
 }
return sum;
```

Or using streams and Collectors.summarizingDouble

```
double sum = konten.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(entry -> entry.getValue().getGuthaben()))
        .getSum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes like user7 said. But instead of using the entrySet() you could also use the values() method.

```
double sum = konten.values()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(konto-> konto.getGuthaben()))
    .getSum();
```